# In JQuery, how do I pre-select an item in my autocomplete list?

Tags: jquery, select, autocomplete

I'm using JQuery 1.11.1.  I have an autocomplete filter whcih I set up like so ...

```
 <input type="text" id="stateFilter" placeholder="Select a State" /><img src="/myproject/resources/images/menu-arrow-closed.png" />
```

and the JS is

```
states = $.map(list, convertListItem);
....
$("#stateFilter").autocomplete({source: states});
```

My question is there are some instances where I'd like to have one of the options selected by default (so the first thing the user sees is not "Select a State" but rather the name of a state selected, e.g. "Virginia").  How do I pre-select an option?  Setting a "value" attribute for my input field does nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery autocomplete textbox set value programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676233/jquery-autocomplete-textbox-set-value-programmatically)

Comment: Actually yes.  This question is the same as the one in your link.  Thanks, -

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing [`search`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search) method `.autocomplete("search", "term")`

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    })
    .autocomplete("search", "JavaScript");
    $("ul.ui-autocomplete")
    .find("li:contains(JavaScript)")
    .trigger("click")
  });
    
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
 
 
</body>
```

Comment: THis displays the option beneath the text box but I would like it actually selected.  In essence, how in JQuery, do I simulate a user clicking on a value from teh list beneath the text box?