# Jquery autocomplete onload

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I'm using the jquery autocomplete plugin.
Everything works as expected , but what I'm after is to trigger the `select` function if there is only one item in the dropdown list, so that fields get auto populated. Essentially setting things up once the page loads.

here's a sample of what I'm doing:

```
$('#auto-complete').autocomplete({
    source:function(){//get data here},
    select:function(e,ui){
     //setting fields here: 
      $('#user').val("");
    },
   focus:function(){}

});
```

I've explored adding on a response function but even that seems to require a change in the autocomplete field first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jquery autocomplete textbox set value programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676233/jquery-autocomplete-textbox-set-value-programmatically)

Comment: The `select` action is only triggered when a User makes a selection. You can trigger it with `.trigger()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Response` callback:

> Triggered after a search completes, before the menu is shown. Useful for local manipulation of suggestion data, where a custom `source` option callback is not required. This event is always triggered when a search completes, even if the menu will not be shown because there are no results or the Autocomplete is disabled.

Source: https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-response

```js
$(function() {
  /*
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    */

  var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript"
  ];


  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    minLength: 0,
    response: function(e, ui) {
      if (ui.content.length == 1) {
        $(this).val(ui.content[0].value);
        $(this).autocomplete("close");
      }
    }
  });

  $("#tags").autocomplete("search", "");
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

This is helpful is testing the the results after your Custom Source is called. I suspect you will need to update it a bit.

Alternately, you can test the results before you send the results to `response()` and if they are only 1, set the `value` at that time.