# Set the value of jQuery combobox programmatically

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, combobox, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using the combobox seen here. https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

I need to be able to programmatically select the value, but can't seem to make anything work.

If I do something like this $('#ui-id-811').click(); it works, but obviously there is no way to predict what id the divs will be. I have also been unable to figure out how to add any custom classes to this menu.

Also tried all the usual methods without any success, like $("#locations option[value=050]").attr('selected', 'selected'); But of course, this would be on the hidden options.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
<ul id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete ui-front" unselectable="on" style="top: 475.219px; left: 505.172px; width: 400px; display: none;"><li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-811" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Elementary School</div></li><li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-812" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">S School</div></li><li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-813" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Middle School</div></li><li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-814" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">District K-8</div></li><li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-815" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">District</div></li><li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-816" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">District 9-12</div></li></ul>
```

To be able to select an item programmatically.

Comment: Use `val()` to set the selected option, as you would any other control

Comment: Not true. That method does not work for the combobox plugin

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19026095/2181514) works for that "combobox", though I suggest using a different `select` replacement, such as [tag:select2].  https://jsfiddle.net/tnm0ac36/

Comment: @ropelletier it does work, just not within the UI of the combobox - which is another reason why jQueryUI should no longer be used. It's very outdated and its controls are lacking basic features - as your example shows. There are far, far better alternatives.

Comment: *it does work, just not within the UI* - so,,, it doesn't work... :P

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan What are these better alternatives; I really just wanted something basic and simple

Comment: @freedomn-m.  Thank you, this works 90%; all I need now is to trigger the change/select event for the combobox. That also seems to be elusive :-(

Comment: I created a forked fiddle from @freedomn-m suggestion. I can create a change event that fires, but the select event for the combobox does not. Specifically here:
'''
$("#combobox").combobox({
  select: function (event, ui) { 
   alert( 'select' );  
    console.log($(this).val()); 
  }
});
'''

Comment: I generally recommend [tag:select2], but asking for plugins is off-topic as a question on SO.

Comment: I'd just move the change event handler to its own function then call that function, ie  `$(..).combobox({select:function(e, ui) { handleComboSelect($(e).val()); }});`  then `handleComboSelect(val)` after setting the combobox value... and move on.

Comment: select2 looks perfect. Thanks for the pointer. I am officially abandoning the combobox plugin in favor of select2. This thread can be ignored.